# multi index dataframe data extraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where in the first row I have multiple entries but the 2nd row has repeating columns.

```
                   A                           B.                     C
Date           High         Low            High       Low.        High        Low       
2000-07-03     19.796038    19.202157      9.261945   9.011265    19.261945   9.011265

2000-07-05     19.845534    18.845534      9.81945    8.011       29.81945    8.011
```

I want to find out which  A , B or C has the biggest difference in high and low along with the date.

```
Desired output:
                     C
         Date        High          Low      Difference 
         2000-07-05  29.81945      8.011.   21.808
```

which is better pivot_table, group_by, melt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ca do `stack` , then `idxmax`

```
s=df.stack(level=0)
idx=(s['High']-s['Low']).idxmax()

df.loc[[idx[0]],[idx[1]]]
Out[268]: 
                   C       
                High    Low
Date                       
2000-07-05  29.81945  8.011
```